# Why does Object.hashcode() have conflicts in Java?

Tags: java, hashcode

I run the code below in Hotspot JDK 1.6 on Windows XP,
I ran it twice and I got the results below.

So basically it seems the `object.hashcode()` also have conflicts?
it looks like it's not returning the memory address in the VM.

However, a comment in the JDK said the values should be distinct, can anyone explain?

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by 
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct 
>   objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal 
>   address of the object into an integer, but this implementation 
>   technique is not required by the 
>   Java<sup>TM</sup> programming language.)
>
> ```
> @return  a hash code value for this object.
> @see     java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
> @see     java.util.Hashtable
> ```

This is the first result:

```
i,hashcode(): 361,9578500
i,hashcode(): 1886,9578500
conflict:1886, 361
i,hashcode(): 1905,14850080
i,hashcode(): 2185,14850080
conflict:2185, 1905
9998
```

This is the 2nd result:

```
i,hashcode(): 361,5462872
i,hashcode(): 1886,29705835
conflict:1887, 362
i,hashcode(): 1905,9949222
i,hashcode(): 2185,2081190
conflict:2186, 1906
9998
10000
```

My code:

```
@Test
    public void testAddr()
    {
        Set<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> m = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        Set<Object> os = new HashSet<Object>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            Object o = new Object();
            os.add(o);
            Integer h = o.hashCode();

            if((i == 361) || (i == 1886) || (i == 2185) || (i == 1905))
            {
                System.out.println("i,hashcode(): " + i + "," + h);
            }

            if(s.contains(h))
            {
                System.out.println("conflict:" + i + ", " + m.get(h));
            }
            else
            {
                s.add(h);   
                m.put(h,  i);
            }

        }


        System.out.println(s.size());

        int c = 0;
        for(Object o: os)
        {
            c++;
        }

        System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Comment: The comment does not say it WILL be distinct, but rather they will try to make it distinct but offer no guarantee

Comment: _"As much as is reasonably practical"_, will it return distinct codes.  No guarantee.

Comment: *As much as is reasonably practical* is the key phrase to understanding of why you see hash code collisions. This is not an error.

Comment: my question would more be: what's the hotspot jdk on windows's implementation of Object.hashcode()? is it returning the memory address of the object? if it is, then it should be distinct here, because I've below codes at the end, which means all the objects are not collected by GC yet;    int c = 0;
        for(Object o: os)
        {
            c++;
        }

Answer (score 5):

`hashCode()` is supposed to be used for placing objects in [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).  The rule for `hashCode` is **not** that `hashCode` should never generate conflicts, although that is a desirable property, but that *equal objects must have equal hash codes*.  This does not preclude non-equal objects from having equal hash codes.

You have found a case where the default `Object.hashCode()` implementation does generate equal hash codes for non-equal objects.  It is required that the hash code of an object not change unless there is a change to some field affection equality of that object with another.  One possible cause is that the garbage collector rearranged memory so that a later instantiation of `o` was at the same location as an earlier instantiation of `o` (that is, you allocated two objects `o` in the loop, and the garbage collector rearranged memory in between the two allocations so that the old `o` was moved out of one location of memory and the new `o` was then allocated at that location).  Then, even though the hash code for the old `o` cannot change, the hash code for the new `o` is the address where the new `o` is stored in memory, which happens to be equal to the hash code for the old `o`.

Comment: The hashCode of an Integer is the value of the Integer.  This means that he got back the same hash code for two of his objects.  I'm not sure how the line you pointed to is a problem..

Comment: @JamesMontagne You are right.  Most classes (rightly) don't specify the implementation details of `hashCode()`, but some core Java classes like `String` do.  I had to check the docs to make sure, but `Integer.hashCode()` does return the underlying value of the integer.  I've edited my answer to make the point more clear.

Comment: my question would more be: what's the hotspot jdk on windows's implementation of Object.hashcode()? is it returning the memory address of the object? if it is, then it should be distinct here, because I've below codes at the end, which means all the objects are not collected by GC yet;    int c = 0;
        for(Object o: os)
        {
            c++;
        }

Comment: @hetaoblog The OpenJDK implementation by default returns a modified version of the address. Obviously the low bits of an address are likely to be zero, and in a power-of-2 simple hash table that would be bad (`HashMap` since about 1.4.1/2 "rehashes" the hash value to scramble the bits up). For debug purposes there are build options to always return 1 (for maximum collisions) or to use a secure random number generator (slow, but a benchmark for minimal collisions). I believe IBM were using an implementation where the hash values were supposed to be unguessable (they weren't, obviously).

Comment: @hetaoblog I don't know exactly how the HotSpot JVM on Windows implements `Object.hashCode()`, but the situation I described in the second paragraph has nothing to do with whether the objects were garbage collected or not.  The JRE is at complete liberty to rearrange memory at will, and one way it may do so is by moving objects between generations (see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#generations).  If the old `o` was moved to the tenured generation and the new `o` was allocated in the young generation, the situation I described could occur.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin thx for reminding me GC and memory move; i did another test with adding -Xloggc:mygc.log and test several times again, the conclusion is still the same, during the test there is no gc involved and there's still conflicts

Answer (score 2):

It's an unfortunately common misinterpretation of the API docs. From a still-unfixed (1 vote) bug for this some time ago.

> [(spec) System.identityHashCode doc inadequate, Object.hashCode default
> implementation docs mislead](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6321873)
>
> [...]
>
> From Usenet discussions and Open Source Software it appears that
> many, perhaps majority, of programmers take this to mean that the
> default implementation, and hence System.identityHashCode, will
> produce unique hashcodes.
>
> The suggested implementation technique is not even appropriate to
> modern handleless JVMs, and should go the same way as JVM Spec Chapter
> 9.
>
> The qualification "As much as is reasonably practical," is, in
> practice, insufficient to make clear that hashcodes are not, in
> practice, distinct.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a long-running program may create, call `hashCode()` upon, and abandon many billions of objects during the time that it runs.  Thus, it would be mathematically impossible to ensure that ensuring that once some object `hashCode` returned a particular number, no other object would ever return that same number for the life of the program.  Even if `hashCode()` somehow managed to return unique values for the first 4,294,967,296 objects, it would have no choice but to return an already-used value for the next one (since the previous call would have used the last remaining formerly-unused value).

The fact that `hashCode()` clearly cannot guarantee that hash values won't get reused for the life of the program does not mean it couldn't guarantee that hash codes won't get reused during the lifetime of the objects in question.  Indeed, for some memory-management schemes, such a guarantee could be made relatively cheaply.  For example, the 1984 Macintosh split the heap into two parts, one of which held fixed-sized object descriptors, and one of which held variable-sized object data.  The object descriptors, once created, would never move; if any objects were deleted, the space used by their descriptors would get reused when new objects were created.  Under such a scheme, the address of an object descriptor would represent a unique and unchanging representation of its identity for as long as the object existed, and could thus be used as a `hashCode()` value.  Unfortunately, such schemes tend to have more overhead than some other approaches in which objects have no fixed address associated with them.

Comment: good perspective that i was not aware of! and thx for providing some interesting background knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The comment does not say that it is distinct.
It says that it is distinct *as much as is reasonably practical*.

Apparently, you found a case where it wasn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

Hashcodes do not have to be unique just consistent.  Although more often than not they are typically fairly unique.

In addition to your excerpt above Object has the following to say.

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)

[Object Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)